# Is there an option to call mocked api inside mocked lambda function without pushing environment?

Tags: aws-amplify

Is there a way to call mocked API mutation that calls mocked lambda which calls mocked API?

During mocking (`amplify mock`) amplify tries to resolve data passed to resource creation. I want to use API inside one of my Lambda functions, so it has reference to ID and APIEndpoint [1] - the problem is that the environment has never been pushed and those values aren't existing. Is there a way to reference "not pushed" API in such environment state(?) or I am doing it wrong and I have to push this environment despite my mindset of having one environment fully local in the mocked state?

[1]: (defaults from amplify function creation with checking the option to use other resources, checked my API, checked create and read)

## Explanation:

Using amplify, I have a local environment (never pushed, using only in the mock state) that contains graphql API and a couple of lambda functions.

When I am trying to `amplify mock` - it is failing due to
`Error: Could not find ref for "apicloudplaygroundapiGraphQLAPIIdOutput"` (cloudplaygroundapi is my api name) when it is creating (mock) lambda function referenced in grapql schema as `registerPlayer: Player @function(name: "registerPlayerFunction-${env}")`.

My mindset there is... If I am only mocking those resources - It shouldn't require proper ID/Endpoints of deployed resources and amplify should mock Outputs for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was using outdated amplify-cli. Command to update CLI is

`sudo npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli@latest`